# Change the setting 'StartWhenAvailable' via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have some scheduled tasks where I'm wanting to set the following setting to true

StartWhenAvailable
which correlates to this setting
[image]

What is the best way in Powershell to achieve this? I wrote the following, but I feel like there is a much better way to do it.

```
$update = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -StartWhenAvailable 
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Adobe Acrobat Update Task' -Settings $update
```

Also, how do you change these values to true/false?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, that's a perfectly valid way to set the `Settings` object.  Another way would be to operate on the objects themselves, which might make sense if you're looping over a series of objects, or similar.

```
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Adobe Acrobat Update Task'
$Settings = $Task.Settings
$Settings.StartWhenAvailable = $true
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Adobe Acrobat Update Task' -Settings $Settings
```

For your second question, the `-StartWhenAvailable` is a `[switch]` in PowerShell - see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasksettingsset).  You can toggle the settings to `$false` by specifying `-StartWhenAvailable:$false`.  See [switch parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#switch-parameters) for more details.